# Drupal 7 Private Files - How to override security in custom module

Tags: hooks, media, theming, security

Is there a hook to override access to images stored in the private file system when theme_image_style is used to output the image?

Answer (score 2):

Image styles are served from the public file system, and there's no hook to control access to public files, so unfortunately not.

There's no simple solution, but there *is* a working solution: [Image Style Access](https://drupal.org/project/image_style_access)

> Allows granular access control to images and image style derivatives.

I've had a quick look through the code and you won't find a better starting point than that module. Quite a straightforward idea actually, it introduces a menu router item for each `./styles/[image-style]` folder, controlled by an access callback.

It does mean you now have the overhead of a full bootstrap for all image styles, but since you want to check access based on the DB there's no other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

@Clive Thanks for the suggestion, in the end I did find an answer to this and it was quite easy.

hook_file_download($uri) https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7

For what I needed this worked just great. It is called everytime a private file is accessed through the drupal system.

I can easily do the checks on the user logged in when this hook is called and just return 1 if the user should be allowed access to the file or -1 if I want to deny access.